Type hint with string constant
I sometimes see people using string constant for type hint, like below:
def my_function(arg1: "some_string", arg2: int) -> None:
    pass

What does arg1: "some_string" mean? Under what condition should we use it like that?

It could be a forward reference, i.e. the name of a type that doesn't exist at the type the annotation is being written. Or it could be an error and they intended to use a Literal.

This document describes the syntax for python annotations. As you can see, they can be any arbitrary python expression, including any random string. Type hinting is just one of the possible applications.
Now, without knowing what was in that string, we cannot know for sure what it was used for in your example, but my guess would be that they are still type hints (as defined in pep 484), enclosed in strings as described in this section of pep 484. For more explanations on that case see this question

It's worth pointing out that while syntactically any expression may be used, semantically such expressions have to be used with type-hinting in mind. (PEP 563 deprecates any function annotations that are incompatible with PEP 484 et al.)

A quoted string is interpreted as a forward hint, in this case some_string is a type that will be defined but has not yet at the time my_function is being defined.
